# How to get rowSums for selected columns in R

Tags: r, rowsum

I am a newbie to R and seek help to calculate sums of selected column for each row. My simple data frame is as below.

```
data = data.frame(location = c("a","b","c","d"),
            v1 = c(3,4,3,3), v2 = c(4,56,3,88), v3 =c(7,6,2,9), v4=c(7,6,1,9),
            v5 =c(4,4,7,9), v6 = c(2,8,4,6))
```

I want sum of columns V1 to V3 and V4 to V6 for my each row in a new data frame.

```
   x1   x2
a  14   13   
b  66   18
c
d
```

I did something like below.

```
rowSums(data[,2:4][,5:7])
```

But something should be wrong in my codes. Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a quite simple solution using `apply`.

```
output <- data.frame( x1 = apply(data[2:4], 1, sum) ,
                      x2 = apply(data[5:7], 1, sum) )
```

result:

```
output
>    x1 x2
> 1  14 13
> 2  66 18
> 3   8 12
> 4 100 24
```

Answer (score 9):

My sense would be to use dply:

```
require(dply)
data %>% mutate(v2v4 = rowSums(.[2:4])) %>% mutate(v4v6 = rowSums(.[5:7])) %>% select(-(location:v6))
```

result:

```
> newDf <- data %>% mutate(v2v4 = rowSums(.[2:4])) %>% mutate(v4v6 = rowSums(.[5:7])) %>% select(-(location:v6))
> newDf
  v2v4 v4v6
1   14   13
2   66   18
3    8   12
4  100   24
```

Answer (score 3):

```
rowSums(cbind(mydata$variable1, mydata$variable2, mydata$variable3), na.rm = T )
```

Answer (score 2):

OK, if you want a separate dataframe:

```
> data.frame(X1=rowSums(data[,2:4]), X2=rowSums(data[,5:7]))
```

Comment: this answer does not return the desired output in `data.frame`

Comment: I've never said it does.  I've said you need to use rowSums(data[,c(2:4,5:7)]) instead of rowSums(data[,2:4][,5:7]).
If you want a dataframe you just need to combine it.

Comment: I still think your answer does not return the result asked for in the questions, which would be a `data.frame` like the ones you can see in the other answers

Comment: Are you sure?.
Check the result, it's a data.frame

Comment: Yes, it's now returning a data.frame, but it's still not returning the desired output indicated in the question.

Answer (score 1):

Specifying the two summations explicitly:

```
cbind(x1=rowSums(data[,c('v1','v2','v3')]),x2=rowSums(data[,c('v4','v5','v6')]));
##       x1 x2
## [1,]  14 13
## [2,]  66 18
## [3,]   8 12
## [4,] 100 24
```

Comment: actual data set has got large number of variables.

Answer (score 0):

We can `split` the dataset into a `list` and then use `Reduce` with `f="+"`.

```
sapply(split.default(data[-1], rep(paste0("x", 1:2), each=3)), Reduce, f=`+`)
#     x1 x2
#[1,]  14 13
#[2,]  66 18
#[3,]   8 12
#[4,] 100 24
```

Comment: All answers work nicely. Thanks . @Akrun what does Reduce, f='+' do here please?

Comment: @Lio  `f` is the function call inside the `Reduce`.  It does the sum by each element in a particular row of the data.frame.

Answer (score 0):

So, I came across a similar problem

I have the same survey of 20 questions given 2 different times, so there are 2 different survey scores, for a total of 40 columns.  Each survey question ends with an identifier.  So for example, the first question of the survey is distinguished by adding .a or .c:

```
Survey1Question1.a
Survey1Question1.c
```

Say your data is in df1 and you want to sum all of the columns *within* each survey so that you have 2 survey scores:

```
df1 %>% mutate(Survey.A = rowSums(.[grepl('\\.a$',colnames(.))]),
        Survey2 = rowSums(.[grepl('\\.c$',colnames(.))]),
        )

# A tibble: 9 x 2
  Survey.A Survey.C
     <dbl>   <dbl>
1       64      51
2       89      91
3       62      60
4       80      80
5       66      69
6       60      61
7       71      74
8       52      50
9       79      69
```

I'm just learning how to use the '.' dot notation.  But I believe this works because rowSums is expecting a dataframe.  [Which means you can follow Technophobe1's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37085690/4485604) above.  But the trick then becomes how can you do that programmatically.

Well, the first '.' in rowSums is the full set of columns/variables in the data set passed by the pipe (df1).  But you want to subset that.

So, here is where grepl works well.  You can subset a dataframe using grepl using the following syntax: `dataframe[,grepl("pattern",colnames(dataframe))]`

So, in my code above `rowSums(.[grepl('\\.a$',colnames(.))])` the trick is substituting 'dataframe' with the '.' dot notation.